# View my android app rating in my app

Tags: android

I want to load rating of my app uploaded in android market in some app.
how to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no provision to get the rating or comment as input from the user.**

**You can only redirect it to the android market URL .**